# Printing a model's value in a view in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm upgrading a Rails 3.0.17 app to Rails 3.1.8 (Ruby 1.9.2) and I'm experiencing a weird behavior on a view. I have an Array of @tasks and I print in the beginning of the view:

```
<%= pluralize(@tasks.first.estimates.last.work_hours, t("hour"), t("hours")) %>
```

It's OK, shows the work_hours attribute from the last estimate within all estimates for the first task on the @tasks array.

But a few lines below I use the same code to print it again, and shows me 0.

Any hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Without seeing the actual code involved, it's hard to say. Are you sure the two lines of code are exactly identical? Is there anything that might be changing the value of work_hours in your model?

Comment: Hi Beerlington, the strange part is that everything goes fine on Rails 3.0.17. I'm suspicious that's something related with lazy loading...

Comment: Actually, I think the problem is a form between the first and the second call to the attribute. That form users ...estimates.new to give user a chance to create a new one. In Rails 3.1 it changes the relation that I use afterwards. I'm going to cache this value in another variable so it persists along the view rendering. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help. That's the type of problem I'd need to sit down with someone on and walk through the code with them.